# Laravel 5.1.0 is out. Should I update my existing site from 5.0 to 5.1 for security reasons?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-validation

I am builing a site in Laravel 5.0, almost on staging server. Now Laravel 5.1 suggests some changes Authentication, Validation and Elequent etc. It also deprecates some other methods. Should I upgrade to Laravel 5.1 for security reasons to make it future proof, or I should just continue with 5.0 and put it on Production server?

Thank you.

Comment: Depends on how long you expect your code to be around and the time you have to convert it. If it’s a small or hobby project, then probably not. If it’s a larger system that will be around for a couple of years, then it may be worth upgrading with 5.1 having long-term support.

Comment: Thank you for your time.  Its definitely not a hobby project. Are there any security implications if I don't upgrade it? I am concerned about that.

Comment: Not really. It’s just a minor version bump.